# Best approach: Displaying a "nothing here, yet" screen instead of empty tableView cells

Tags: ios, uitableview

When opening a `UITableViewController`, I'd like to display a screen saying "nothing here, yet" (c.f. screenshot of the Dropbox App below) instead of empty rows when there are no sections/rows. This is done in multiple Apps already, but I'd like to know if there is a recommended way of achieving this.

[image: Dropbox: empty favorites tab]

I can imagine multiple ways of doing this, including

- adding a `UIView` as a subView to the view of the tableViewController
- switching to a `UIViewController` and implementing the tableView behavior on my own
- setting the `UIView` as the `backgroundView` and hiding the tableView cells

Thank you for all your ideas!

Comment: Second approach is good IMHO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a new (as of June 2014) library called [DZNEmptyDataSet](https://github.com/dzenbot/DZNEmptyDataSet) handling exactly this case. It uses the first approach (UIView as a subview) described in the question. Pretty neat realisation.

Answer (score 1):

The way I usually do it, is displaying a single custom cell when there's nothing to display.

Comment: @tilo this is a good idea, one cell with width and height of the screen, maybe even "user interaction disabled" at this point.

Comment: Exact! Or just disable scroll, just like @iphonic.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I didn't think about using a custom cell and like the idea. However, this approach does not seem to be well suited for a grouped table view, right? This is irrelevant in my case, as I'm not using one, but could be important for others.

Comment: @tilo For grouped tableviews, I use the footer section: `-tableView:titleForFooterInSection:`. I use footer because it is already centered. But if you wand to display more than just some text you can use the `-tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:` method to display a custom view. Anyway, I'm glad you find my idea relevant in your own case. It could deserve a little answer acceptation ;o)

Answer (score 0):

You must be having some data array through which you can define few things, in table view.. You can achieve this in your tableview only with its delegate methods..

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    if([dataArr count] == 0)
     return 1;
    return [dataArr count];
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
      if([dataArr count]==0){
          return self.view.frame.size.height;

      }
  return 44.0;
}
```

and then

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
     if([dataArr count]==0){
        //Create a cell with the no data image
        tableView.scrollEnabled=NO;
     }else{
         //Create your default cell with data..
         tableView.scrollEnabled=YES;
     }

   return nil;
}
```

I am just giving you an idea, its your choice of using it..